# ThreeJS disable rendering of faces behind the Camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am Writing a **Panorama Viewer**. The Image is Displayed in a Sphere with a variable amount of faces.
I want it only to render the faces in the camera direction (for better performance).

Does ThreeJS do this automatically or can I declare specific faces of a mash that do not get rendered?

like `mash.faces[5].rendered = false;` or so.

Comment: I believe that if you've not cancelled the frustrum checking, it ThreeJS do this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process is called **[viewing frustum culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum)** and ThreeJS takes care of this.

ThreeJS also takes care of **[font and/or backface culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling)** depending on your material settings. Meaning that only the visible side of the faces are rendered.

[Here in the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Frustum) you can find the ThreeJS Frustum.

And if the `frustumCulled` property on `THREE.Object3D` manages frustum culling and [is by default set to true](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L69).

Answer (score 0):

If rolling your own vertices, edges, indices, a triangle with vertices stored in counterclockwise order is said to be front facing by default :

```
"To activate face culling, GL_CULL_FACE​ must first be enabled with glEnable​. By default, face culling is disabled"
```