# How to find the faces that appear on the screen?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my application, a user is browsing a scene, and I'd like to be able to find the faces that appear on the screen meaning that the user can see it (so I'd like to exclude the faces that are not in the frustum of the camera, and the faces that are hidden by other faces).

An idea I had was to use the [`Raycaster`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster) class to throw rays on each pixel of the screen, but I'm afraid the performances will be low (I don't need it to be realtime but I'd like it not to be really slow).

I know that there is a z-buffer to know which faces are shown because they are not hidden and I wanted to know if there was an easy way with Three.js to use the z-buffer to find those faces.

Thank you !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056352/threejs-disable-rendering-of-faces-behind-the-camera

Comment: Thanks, but I know that Three.js does face culling. My question is more "How could I know which faces are not drawn because of the culling, and which are ?". Would I have to modify Three.js library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is the following :

- I use three.js server-side to render my model (people [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2182),  and [there](http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/129341221225/look-ma-no-canvas-server-side-3d-rendering-with) explain how to do it).
- I use the `color` attribute of [`Face3`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Face3) in order to set a specific color for each face. Each face has a number (the number of the face in the `.obj` file), this number will be represent the `Face3` color.
- I use only ambient light
- I do the rendering

My render represents in fact a set of pixels : if a certain color appears on the rendering, it means that the face corresponding the color is appearing on the screen.