# Optimize Three.JS render time for a static scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, renderer

I have a scene which contains 15-20 objects, 4 lights. And properties of my renderer are

```
function getRenderer(container, width, height) {
    var renderer;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: false, antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: false });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xCCE0FF), 1);
    renderer.gammaInput = true;
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    renderer.clear();

    return renderer;
}
```

My render loop renders the scene every second.

```
    function renderLoop() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    setTimeout(function () {
        renderLoop();
    }, 1000);
}
```

The problem I am facing is `this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)` is taking about 100 ms to render the scene but I want it to be below 33ms so that I can have frame rate of at least 30 fps.

Is there a way to optimize the renderer performance by any means (like changing any properties or something)?

I don't want to use worker.js as my scene is static and doesn't contain any complex calculations.

Comment: First of all use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of setTimeout. Secondly, use [BufferGeometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry) instead of [Geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry)

Comment: Another tip is to merge your geometries.

Comment: Maybe you can try to render only what's visible. Check this out:
[ThreeJS disable rendering of faces behind the Camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056352/threejs-disable-rendering-of-faces-behind-the-camera)

Comment: Changed setTimeOut to requestAnimationFrame and I am already merging the geometries, but they didn't affect the rendering time much.@AlexanderPopov

Comment: rendering only visible objects decreased rendering time from 100ms to 85ms.Thanks for the suggestion. But I want to get it to <30ms.Anymore suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a static scene, there is no reason to have an animation loop. You just have to render once after the scene -- and all your assets -- load.

That is why there are callbacks for the loader functions. And that is why there is a `THREE.LoadingManager`.

There are many possible use cases. Study the three.js examples to find solutions for your particular use case.

If you are using `OrbitControls` to control the camera, you can force a re-render whenever the camera moves, like so:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use if there is no animation loop
```

three.js r.75

Comment: Currently my scene is static but I have to add motion to it later on, if static scene is taking more time to render then the scene with motion will take much more time, so I am trying to fix the rendering time of static scene first.Makes sense?